# docker-machine - sudo systemctl -f start docker err : exit status 255 output

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-machine

Currently having issues using docker-machine. Running:

```
docker-machine \
create \
<testname> \
--driver generic  \
--generic-ip-address <ip address> \
--engine-storage-driver=overlay \
--generic-ssh-user <username>
```

Results in some processing, and eventually an error:

> About to run SSH command:
>
> sudo systemctl -f start docker
>
> SSH cmd err, output: exit status 255: 
>   Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: ssh command error:
>   command : sudo systemctl -f start docker
>   err     : exit status 255
>   output  : 
>   notifying bugsnag: [Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: > ssh command error:
>   command : sudo systemctl -f start docker
>   err     : exit status 255
>   output  : ]

I'm not really sure about how to progress next, `--debug` does not really give much more detail. There are loads of similar issues posted on GitHub which don't really help.

I am running the command on my laptop Ubuntu 16.04 to a remote VM (Ubuntu 16.04)

I suppose, the other question is, do I actually need to use docker-machine i.e. should I just point the client to the docker engine on VM (security concern?)

I was intending to run docker-compose locally then deploy via docker-machine like [here](https://medium.com/@theotow/easy-deploy-a-nodejs-app-to-prod-and-staging-with-docker-f7e6ff406b69).

Any suggestions / help appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You don't need docker-machine, you can do it directly

Comment: Thanks @TarunLalwani. Do you mean doing something like [this](https://github.com/IcaliaLabs/guides/wiki/Deploy-and-Secure-a-Remote-Docker-Engine)?

Comment: Yes exactly like that